# add unary operator in expression tree

Tags: c++, tree, expression

I am doing my assignment in which I have to modify my previous task (which is prefix expression tree which takes expression and give result)

```
+ OR
* AND
- NOT
```

Now I have to make it Logic expression tree which will perform AND OR and NOT operations

```
char input;
    cin.get(input);

    if((input == '+')||(input == '-')||(input == '*'))
        {
        p = new ExprTreeNode(input,NULL,NULL);
         buildSub(p->left);
         buildSub(p->right);
      }
      else if(isdigit(input))
        {     //create a new node
            p = new ExprTreeNode(input,NULL,NULL);
        }
        else
      {
        cout <<" invalid expression exiting..." <<endl;
         exit (1);
       }
```

above code reads expression and makes tree using recursion...

I am confused how I can add unary operator that is NOT... 
after that I have to evaluate expression

```
int answer;
    switch (p->dataItem){

        case '*':
            // AND
        case'+':
            // OR

        case '-':
            // Reverse

        default:
            answer = (p->dataItem-'0');
            break;
    }
    return answer;
```

p is ExprTreeNode

```
// Data members
        char dataItem;          // Expression tree data item
        ExprTreeNode *left,     // Pointer to the left child
                     *right;    // Pointer to the right child
```

Comment: First, remove the `if( p == NULL)` check. `p` will never be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you want to do the following:

```
if ((input == '+') || (input == '*'))
{
  p = new ExprTreeNode(input,NULL,NULL);
  buildSub(p->left);
  buildSub(p->right);
}
else if (input == '-')
{
  p = new ExprTreeNode(input, NULL, NULL);
  buildSub(p->left);
}
else if(isdigit(input))
{     //create a new node
  p = new ExprTreeNode(input,NULL,NULL);
}
else
{
  cout <<" invalid expression exiting..." <<endl;
  exit (1);
}
```

**Edit:**
Then, the evaluation routine could work like this:

```
bool ExprTreeNode::evaluate() {
  switch (dataItem) {
    case '+':
      return left->evaluate() || right->evaluate();
    case '*':
      return left->evaluate() && right->evaluate();
    case '-':
      return !left->evaluate();
    case '0':
      return false;
    default:
      return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: @user1759804 It seems the terminals (data) in your tree are integers (as you defined `int answer`). Is the tree supposed to do logic operations (just true/false), or bitwise operations on numbers?

Comment: it is integer data
input would be like this
*+10+01

Comment: @user1759804 You're rather tight-lipped about what you want to achieve. Could you edit your question to describe the problem better and provide an example of input and desired output? You have to be as specific as possible to enable others to help you.

Comment: :P sorry about that....
input data *+10+01
output would be 1

((1+0)*(0+1)) it will give ans 1 as 1 OR 0 gives result 1 and 1 AND 1 also gives 1

em not facing problem in this
but when i use +*10*1-0 (NOT operator... i have no idea how to parse it)

Comment: edit a little bit and now its working finally... thanks alot <3